# timeIntervalSinceDate problem

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, datetime, date-comparison

last resort this as I cannot for the life of me work it out!

I am setting a date when my app is closed (using applicationWillTerminate) in user defaults

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDate *timeClosed = [[NSDate alloc] init];
[defaults setObject: timeClosed forKey:@"svdTimeClosedApp"];
```

then when the app is launched, I want to compare this time using

```
NSDate *timeSaved = svdTimeClosedApp;
NSDate *timeNow = [[NSDate alloc] init];
double timeInterval = [timeSaved timeIntervalSinceDate:timeNow];
NSLog(@"time now = %@, time saved = %@, time diff = %@", timeNow, timeSaved, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",timeInterval]);
```

I tried to output this to the log window expecting to see a nicely formatted string of around 20 seconds. Trouble is, it's coming out as 2047868928!

Any ideas?!

(output of the log window below)

```
time now = 2009-12-19 20:54:02 +0000, time saved = 2009-12-19 20:48:29 +0000, time diff = 2047868928
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

there are a couple of issues. First, in your `stringWithFormat:` you want to use %g, not %d, %d is for integer values. Also, you should do `[timeNow timeIntervalSinceDate:timeSaved]` your current call will give you a negative value.

Comment: that's done it! [time diff = 4.71526] - it was the stringwithformat that wasn't correct. Can't believe that's all it was!

Thanks very much guys!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code I use.

In my app, when the user syncs some data, I record the current date/time using this code:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"LastSyncDate"];
[prefs synchronize];
```

Then, if I want to see how many days it's been since they last synced, I can use this:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDate* dateOfLastSync = [prefs objectForKey:@"LastSyncDate"];
if (dateOfLastSync != nil)
{
    NSDate *timeNow = [NSDate date];
    double SECONDS_TO_DAY = 60 * 60 * 24;
    int timeIntervalInDays = (int)([timeNow timeIntervalSinceDate:dateOfLastSync] / SECONDS_TO_DAY);
    NSLog(@"The last sync was %d days ago.", timeIntervalInDays);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Mike

[www.MikesKnowledgeBase.com](http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your `timeInterval` calculation backwards, don't you? I think you want to say it reversed.

```
double timeInterval = [timeNow timeIntervalSinceDate:timeSaved];
```

Comment: I did try that, the result was

time now = 2009-12-19 21:28:28 +0000, time saved = 2009-12-19 21:28:24 +0000, time diff = -201326592

Given that there was 4 seconds shown - I would assume time diff should be 4. I'm wondering whether I need to format the dates to strings first to get the hours, minutes and seconds...